# How to get Views from YouTube Video URL in Android?

Tags: android, video, view, youtube

How to get Views from YouTube Video URL in Android ?

Just for Example, I have YouTube URL
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPhZezbxd8o&feature=topvideos_music

Then how do I get Views from this Video URL in Android ?

Comment: Checkout: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/show-youtube-user-videos-in-a-listview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this use
[Resources for Mobile Development with YouTube](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/articles/youtube_mobileresources.html)